# WinSCP connection failed when session uses "script" command

Tags: linux, winscp

I am new to WinSCP.
I would like to ask you about WinSCP's limitations and side effects.

This is my current enviroment.
WinSCP Version: 5.9.3
Protocol: SFTP
Target Server: CentOS

I inserted `script` command in target server to track user operations.
Here is the `script` command in `.bash_profile`

```
......
script -f /tmp/`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`_$USER.log
[EOF]
```

That command runs first whenever user's terminal starts opening.

After I inserted the command in target server, I connected target server via WinSCP.

Even WinSCP can be opened, I can't open WinSCP's Terminal.
[Please refer here for WinSCP Log about this case.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2b_R5fvseHzT3JKbnlSUmQxVEk)

I found on WinSCP's official site that

> WinSCP does not support commands that require terminal emulation or user input.

My understanding is 
When WinSCP's terminal opens, `script` command runs in that terminal automatically.
After `script` commands runs, error occurred.
Please refer above link for WinSCP Log.

I executed `script` command while the command haven't inserted in target server as environment variable.
I got error message.
[Please refer here for winSCP Log about this case.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2b_R5fvseHzb0wwWVpPZEhINUU)

May I know the followings...
**How does `script` command concerns with WinSCP's limitation?

What's the effect of `script` command on WinSCP?**

Thanks
Myo Min Thein

Comment: What does the command do?

Comment: script command is used to track user's operations that are executed in linux's terminal.

Comment: OK, so it starts something like a new shell, right?

Comment: Yes.
When I open winSCP's terminal, it open new shell. 
And the script command execute for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command starts something like a new shell.

That shell ignores a fact that WinSCP started a non-interactive session. In the non-interactive session, the standard shells (bash, etc) do not display prompts. While the `script` shell does display prompts (`[root@orctdbm20 ~]#`). WinSCP is not able to cope with that.

---

A reason, why you cannot execute the command in the Terminal window is different. It's because the command *"require ... user input"*. It's not a simple command that does something and exits. It starts a new interactive session (and expects a user input).

Comment: Thanks you.
So, 'script' command is one of WinSCP's Terminal Limitations, right?

Comment: In respect to a use in the Terminal window, yes. When using as an initial shell, then it's rather a non-standard behavior of the `script`, than WinSCP limitation.